# How to create dynamic multilevel related data version table in informatica

Tags: sql, t-sql, plsql, informatica

In one table i have user id and action. for each action as action2 the userid will change from original to the new id. However the change is a part of the same users history. Like below data.

```
ProductID ACTION PreviousID

1001   action1 

1002   action2 1001

1003   action2 1002

1003   action1 1003
```

I need to find a way to assign a unique value that identifies these actions as belonging to one user.

```
ProductID ACTION UNIQID

1001   action1   100

1002   action2 100

1003   action2 100

1003   action1 100
```

How to achieve this using Informatica.

first step is to link the data as productid<-(previousid-productid)<-(previousid-productid)<-(previousid-productid)

each records productid is related to the main product through its previousproductid as shown below. How to achieve this using SQL?

I can do this using stored procedure, However looking for a solution in Informatica.

Emman

Comment: An override on the SQ is ok? Or you are looking for pure informatica design?

Comment: @sagi solution in SQL or Informatica or both is fine. Though I can achieve it using PLSQL, I'm looking for other options than PLSQL.